# DataDog logging image reporting errors in docker logs

Tags: docker, logging, docker-compose, filesystems, datadog

Using datadog docker image, with the following in docker-compos

```
datadog:
  agent: true
  privileged: true
  environment:
    - DD_API_KEY=${DATADOG_API_KEY}
    - DD_APM_ENABLED=true
    - DD_LOGS_ENABLED=true
    - DD_LOGS_CONFIG_CONTAINER_COLLECT_ALL=true
  image: datadog/agent:latest
  volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
    - /proc/:/host/proc/:ro
    - /cgroup/:/host/sys/fs/cgroup:ro
```

I am getting the following errors continuously

> 2018-07-14 16:10:04 UTC | ERROR | (runner.go:277 in work) | Error running check disk: [{"message": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/host/proc/filesystems'", "traceback": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/opt/datadog-agent/embedded/lib/python2.7/site-packages/datadog_checks/checks/base.py\", line 294, in run\n    self.check(copy.deepcopy(self.instances[0]))\n  File \"/opt/datadog-agent/embedded/lib/python2.7/site-packages/datadog_checks/disk/disk.py\", line 43, in check\n    self.collect_metrics_psutil()\n  File \"/opt/datadog-agent/embedded/lib/python2.7/site-packages/datadog_checks/disk/disk.py\", line 90, in collect_metrics_psutil\n    for part in psutil.disk_partitions(all=True):\n  File \"/opt/datadog-agent/embedded/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psutil/**init**.py\", line 1839, in disk_partitions\n    return _psplatform.disk_partitions(all)\n  File \"/opt/datadog-agent/embedded/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psutil/_pslinux.py\", line 1000, in disk_partitions\n    with open_text(\"%s/filesystems\" % get_procfs_path()) as f:\n  File \"/opt/datadog-agent/embedded/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psutil/_pslinux.py\", line 194, in open_text\n    return open(fname, \"rt\", **kwargs)\nIOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/host/proc/filesystems'\n"}]

and another

> 2018-07-14 16:10:04 UTC | WARN | (cgroup.go:510 in
>   parseCgroupMountPoints) | No mountPoints were detected, current cgroup
>   root is: /host/sys/fs/cgroup/

Any ideas what it means or how to debug it? Expecting to get logs into datadog from other containers sysout so I have all logs in one place. I can see it successfully detects the other containers

Note the docker image is using version 6 of datadog
Thanks

Comment: if you haven't already, you'll probably want to reach out to support@datadoghq.com about this.

Comment: I have the same issue. I was able to define my volume with `-v - /proc/:/host/proc/:ro` but no `filesystems` when checking the dir through bash